# Adjust <div>-height to window-height on Bootstrap website

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Assume I have a simple website made with **Bootstrap 4** containing header, navbar, content-area and footer.
My demo-website can be found and live-edited on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/26zda5xv/2/
Please find below a screenshot of the website too:

[image: Screenshot of Demo-Website]

I want the `<div class="container">` to fill out the whole page/window-height at least. (`min-height?`)
This should be done by extending the height of the `<div id="content">`.

Of course the solution should take care of various screen-resolutions/devices automatically.

How to do this correctly based on the JSFiddle?
Is there a build-in solution in Bootstrap 4 for this task?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve this we need 2 steps:

1. add `d-flex flex-column min-vh-100` classes to the container.
2. add `flex-grow-1` class to the content div

[see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9h0bx2de/)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body class="bg-secondary">

  <div class="container bg-white shadow border border-dark d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">

    <img src="http://www.apexcartage.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/placeholder-blue.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    </nav>

    <div id="content" class="my-3 flex-grow-1">
      <p class="h3">Content</p>
    </div>

    <footer>

      <div class="bg-dark text-white mt-4 p-3 border-info" style="border-top: 4px solid">
        <h5 class="title">Footer</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="bg-info p-1"></div>

    </footer>

  </div>

</body>
```